# RecyclerView items are not painted properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my ViewHolder, I have this method, that is called in the adapter when `onBindViewHolder`:

```
protected void bindViews(Item item) {
    dateTextView.setText(item.getDate());
    titleTxtView.setText(item.getTitle());
    if (item.hasMenu()) {
        Log.d("tag", "Item " + item.getId() + " has menu");
        menuButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    } else {
        menuButton.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

But there are `Item`s that doesn't have menu (that is `hasMenu()` returns false) but `menuButton` is shown and vice versa.

I think is because the item recycling because I have 100 items and just 2 have menu. It prints:

> Item 31 has menu
>
> Item 78 has menu

That's ok. However, in the app I can see that some other items are showing the `menuButton` and they shouldn't.

Should I force repaint each item when show/hide the `menuButton`? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Use getitemviewtype to inflate two different layout,one with menu and other without the menu.

Comment: Done, it works perfect, thanks :) Post it as answer.

Comment: Thanks.Glad to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use    **public int getItemViewType(int position)** and  **public int getItemCount()** to inflate two different layout,one with menu and other without the menu.