# Change Recycler view item background color by code

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to change the background color of my RecyclerView item. I think I should be able to do it in  `onBindViewHolder` method but I am not able to do this. I only get bottom border color of the item changed but I want to change the full background color

Here is what I want

```
public void onBindViewHolder(InstalledFontViewRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (//Some Condition) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

I think this should produce something like

[image]

What I get is this

[image]

Here is my RecyclerView Fragment layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/installed_recyclerView"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my item layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="1dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/post_card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arial New"
            android:id="@+id/installed_font_name"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monotype Solutions"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/installed_preview_company_name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preview Test"
            android:id="@+id/installed_preview_textview"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/installed_preview_Unnstall">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Uninstall"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/installed_preview_flip_layout"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Flip This"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you post layout's xml?

Comment: Please paste the xml code as @pawelo requested so we can check something.

Comment: Please try my answer mentioned below.

Comment: What is the build tool version you are using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849759/recyclerview-items-are-not-painted-properly/38849956#38849956

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to change the code in onBindViewHolder as below

```
if(// Any Condition) {  
    ((CardView)holder.post_card_view).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
}
else
{
     ((CardView)holder.post_card_view).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

I hope this will help you , Feel free to comment.

Comment: This answer could be better. ViewHolder pattern was introduced to get rid of using findViewById() and explicit casting when binding data. Those operations are considered expensive and don't need to be repeated on every onBindViewHolder() call

Comment: I am not sure if it is better but there is a viewType: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. I had been using this concept since a long time, but recently I faced a problem, ie, during very fast or slow scroll, the background color changed where it shouldn't have. So I manipulated views via getItemViewType(). 
Surprisingly, changing visibility of a view within a viewHolder in onBindViewHolder works perfectly well. I don't know what causes this abrupt behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

I think that holder.itemView is not CardView but LinearLayout which holds CardView. Try something like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(InstalledFontViewRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (//Some Condition) {
        holder.yourCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
    }
    else {
        holder.yourCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@pankaj as @pawelo said casting can be costly sometimes so the best solution would be to give transparent color to CardView in xml like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/post_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">
```

and then set background color to holder itemView like this.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(InstalledFontViewRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (//Some Condition) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

now it should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above answers in my project, it worked but Android studio gave me errors.
So I used `holder.text_container.setBackgroundResource(R.color.category_numbers);` instead and the red lines were gone. I used color from my custom resource.
I hope this helps someone.